# Android 5 Asus ZenFone 2 blocking push notifications when app close

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I have been testing my app on an Android 5 ZenFone 2. This phone contains a piece of Asus software called autostart manager.

Some detrimental scenarios for my cordova app:

1. After app is installed autostart manager automatically denies it autostart. The big problem here is that the app doesn't receive push notifications when it is neither running in foreground or background. If the user kills the app from task manager then no more notifications (unlikely what the user desires).
2. The app appears to be killed automatically a few mins after being placed in the background. I am assuming this is autostart trying to conserve memory. Again no push notifications.

My app is functionally reliant on being able to receive push notes when not in foreground.

I reckon most average users are not aware that their apps may not be receiving push and therefore not fully functional.

I am wondering:

1. Are there autostartmanager equivalents for other Android devices doing the same thing?
2. Is it possible to beat this software and allow push notification always to be received by editing manifest configuration?

Comment: is it working fine on other devices with android 5

Comment: Unsure about android 5. That's one of the things I'm asking. Works in android 4 and ios.

Comment: Did you ind a solution? We are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is no way too make push notifications work unless you app is marked as "allowed" to start in the Autostart Manager.

There are a lot of app like the Asus Autostart Manager in the Play Store, but generally a user needs to explicitly install one, while the Asus one is preinstalled and non-removable (at least it starts again after the next update which happens quite often for Asus).

Comment: is there a way to already allow the app in autostart manager after installing like in viber it doesn't ask to allow it but it is already allow when checking the autostart manager?

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem.
Go to -> Sound & Notification -> Notification access -> Enable for ZenUI Launcher.
Go to -> Apps and enable notificatio

Comment: Could you please clarify the answer. It will be helpful if it really meant something